What's the relationship between the weight of transposeconv and its corresponding conv given groups > 1?
I'm simulating the workflow of convtranspose function in pytorch, thus I'm thinking of setting the weight of grouped convtranspose to its corresponding grouped conv, and I have tested like this:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
class SimulatedTransposeConv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channel, output_channel, k_h, k_w, s_w, p_w,groups, weight, bias) -> None:
        super().__init__()  
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_channel, output_channel ,kernel_size = (k_h, k_w), stride = (1, 1), groups=groups)
        self.output_channel = output_channel
        self.input_channel = input_channel
        self.pad_insert = s_w - 1
        self.pad_sides = k_w - p_w - 1
        with torch.no_grad():
            weight = weight.flip([-1, -2]).permute(1,0,2,3).reshape(output_channel, input_channel // groups, k_h, k_w)
            self.conv1.weight.copy_(weight)
            self.conv1.bias.copy_(bias)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pad(x, self.pad_insert, self.pad_sides)
        return self.conv1(x)
    def pad(self, x, pad_insert, pad_sides):
        '''It's written in C style'''
        b = x.shape[0]
        c = x.shape[1]
        h = x.shape[2]
        w = x.shape[3]
        pad_w_size = pad_sides * 2 + pad_insert* (w - 1) + w
        res = torch.zeros(pad_w_size * b * h * c)
        x = x.flatten()
        for k in range(c):
            for i in range(h):
                for j in range(w):
                    res[k * h * pad_w_size + i * pad_w_size  + j * (pad_insert + 1)+ pad_sides] = x[k * h * w + i * w + j]
        return res.reshape(b ,c ,h, pad_w_size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k_h = 3
    k_w = 3
    p_w = 0
    s_w = 1
    groups = 8
    tranpose2d = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 8, out_channels = 8, kernel_size = (k_h, k_w), stride = (1, s_w), padding = (k_h - 1, p_w), groups=groups)
    simulated_transpose2d = SimulatedTransposeConv2d(8, 8, k_h, k_w, s_w, p_w, groups, tranpose2d.state_dict()['weight'], tranpose2d.state_dict()['bias']) 
    x = torch.rand((1 ,8 ,8, 8)).type(torch.float32)
    print((tranpose2d(x) - simulated_transpose2d(x)).abs().mean())
    

according to my code, If the groups=1 or the groups = input_channel, the result will be right, but if the groups parameter is not in the situations above(eg input_channel = 8 and groups = 4), the result will be wrong, I think it's probably because the weight relationship between convtranspose and conv is not correct weight_conv=weight_transpose.flip([-1,-2]).permute(1,0,2,3).reshape(output_channel, input_channel // groups, k_h, k_w),is the way of thinking right? If it is correct, so what's the relationship between them? Thanks!
